# Reversing Edge Flow Direction with NetEdit

Tags: simulation, simulator, sumo

I have a network with two edges, with flow going in different directions. I want it to become two edges, with the flow in the same direction. I tried to reverse the edges using Edge operations-> reverse edge, but after saving the network it becomes a single edge instead of two. can somebody help me out?

Comment: I just tried here and it worked. Are you really sure it is only a single edge and not two edges on top of each other? Have a look at "overlapped elements" in the top left corner of netedit.

Comment: Is two edges not a single edge

Comment: I am not sure whether this is a question or a statement. If it is a statement, then the problem is solved. If you want to move the edges such that they do not overlap you can do so by the move mode in netedit

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not put the question the right way, but it's a question. I wish i can get your email to send to you the images, so that you can understand better. I'm really in need of your help sir.

Comment: As far as I know you can add images here too but you can also write to the SUMO mailing list, see https://www.eclipse.org/sumo/contact/